# sharepoint 2010 client objects search

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

I'm just getting into Client Objects, writing Caml querys to retrieve lists and items and presenting the output in an asp.net MVC environment and all works fine. The idea is to use MVC as a presentation layer and Sharepoint as a repository, for various business reasons (like harnessing workflow, business process and all the good things about sharepoint)

The issue that I'm not sure about is offering up 'search'. Is there a way of using client objects to run a Sharepoint Search, and retrieve the resuilts (as a list of items for example?)

Any help or experience greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model doesn't include APIs for Search. As an alternative, you could use the Search Web Service. Here are a few resources:

[Windows SharePoint Services Query Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470518%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

[Creating Search Queries Programmatically by Using the Search Web Service in SharePoint Server 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625950%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

[How to: Query Search using the Web Service](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2008/07/17/how-to-query-search-using-the-web-service.aspx)